Unhandled exception in Visual Studio 2022 with an ASP.NET Core Web API project
Using Visual Studio since the early 2000's, currently at Visual Studio 2022 Professional, vanilla install. I've uninstalled everything, ran install-cleanup and re-installed fresh.
Environment:

IDE: Visual Studio 2022 64-bit, version 17.12.0
O/S: Windows 10 Enterprise, Build 19045.5011
SDK's installed: 5.0.416, 8.0.404 and 9.0.100

Vanilla project, literally select "New Project -> ASP.NET Core Web API -> Next -> Accept all defaults" and attempt to start the project. I get the exception immediately. Targeting the .NET 8.0 Framework
appsettings.json:
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

Any ideas?


Post appsettings.json. The message is quite clear. You have a configuration problem.

Just added it now to question. It's a vanilla project, so the standard appsettings.json that gets added on any new .net core project

I'm afraid that we could try to run dotnet run command within the project folder and see whether this api could work well. It can help confirm whether it's a project issue or the VS issue. If the app could run successfully with dotnet cli, we might try to repair VS.

It was the directory where my projects were stored. I (usually) store my projects in a directory in my user folder (C:\users<username>), which my organisation has access to.
I moved the project to a directory on the root of my orgs laptop hard drive and it started fine.
Ive sent a strongly worded email to our IT asking if a new permissions policy was enforced or similar in recent weeks.
